# How to configure hostapd.conf for wps push button?

Tags: linux, shell-script, command-line, wifi-hotspot, wps

I have android6.0.1
I want to enable the wps when hotspot on.

Can anyone give some ideas and give whatever changes i want to do in someother files.?

Can anyone provide any application for wps server.?

Thanks,
VinothS,

Answer (score 6):

Funny coincidence. I was looking for this, too, today for Debian. Currently I'm following:

http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/NetBSD-current/src/external/bsd/wpa/dist/hostapd/README-WPS
and a bit of
https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/hostapd/hostapd.conf

I just needed to copy these lines:

```
wpa_psk_file=/home/<username>/etc/hostapd/hostapd.psk
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
eap_server=1
wps_state=2
ap_setup_locked=1
wps_pin_requests=/var/run/hostapd.pin-req
device_name=USB2.0 WLAN
manufacturer=ATHEROS
model_name=WAP
model_number=123
serial_number=12345
device_type=6-0050F204-1
os_version=01020300
config_methods=label display push_button keypad
```

into my `hostapd.conf` file. I created a custom one for myself in `~/etc/hostapd.conf`, but normally there is one in `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`.
In your case you might have to change `device_type`. I tried to mostly verify the information like manufacturer, ... but I don't think they are that important. I was able to find `manufacturer` and `serial number` using `lsusb` and then `sudo lsusb -v -s 5:7` (the numbers after `-s` are the bus and device numbers shown by `lsusb`)

After that I restarted `hostapd` with the new configuration file:

```
sudo pkill hostapd
sudo bash -c "nohup hostapd '$HOME/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf' > '$HOME/nohupHostapd.out'" &
```

and did a quick `sudo hostapd_cli wps_pbc` and then was able to connect the printer using WPS.

Comment: Hi
Thank you for your reply. 
I have the doubt now. 
I can not find "var/run" this one default or created automatically. 
And which wifi module are used? I am using wl1831. 

Thanks,
VinothS,

Comment: When i try i got error like that                                                root@sabresd_6dq:/ # hostapd_cli wps_pbc
Failed to connect to hostapd - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory Can you provide some ideas.?                                                                       Thanks, VinothS,

Comment: `/var/run/hostapd` is created automatically. The error message `Failed to connect to hostapd` should only happen if you forgot the line `ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd` or if you apply the changes by restarting hostapd, see also [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=63045) Note that I didn't need to add `ctrl_interface_group=0` like the answers writes. If `/var/run/` itself is missing, then I can't really help.Must be an android problem then. Try creating it with mkdir...

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply,
I try everything.But, i got error

root@sabresd_6dq:/system/etc/wifi # start hostapd                              
init: Starting service 'hostapd'...
root@sabresd_6dq:/system/etc/wifi # init: Service 'hostapd' (pid 2276) exited with status 1

hostapd_cli wps_pbc
Failed to connect to hostapd - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory

Help me and give some more suggestion. 
Thanks,
VinothS,

Comment: Having the same issue, actually. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, will try to mkdir it, maybe that'll take care of the issue.

Comment: It is very hard to debug over the internet. My guess is, that both of you aren't doing this on your router. I have a WLAN-stick for my PC which I use to make a hotspot with which my printer then connects. I.e. it is directly connected to my PC where I configure hostapd. "failed to connect" means most likely hostapd isn't running or was configured wrong or even with the wrong config-file. E.g. check with `ps aux | grep hostapd`. I don't know how you start hostapd, but I do with `sudo pkill hostapd` and `sudo bash -c "nohup hostapd '$HOME/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf' > '$HOME/nohupHostapd.out'" &`

Comment: Hi, are you try in Linux.? or Android.? Why because i was tried in Android.? May be it's work or possible in Linux. But, not sure at Android.

Comment: I'm using Linux. Android uses the Linux kernel and many Linux programs like hostapd, but there still might be differences, yes. I can't really test it on mine, because I haven't rooted my smartphone.

Comment: Hi  mxmlnkn. I already have rooted  phone. Do you know any possible to work in android?. And what are the important things when i try this one. I want some configuration file related to this like android.conf and hostapd.conf. and are you configured dhcpcd.conf file. and which wifi-chip you are used?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help anymore. My android skills are basically none. Stackoverflow also isn't suited for many follow-up questions. You might be better off asking in an Android forum or wait for another answer to your question if my answer isn't working for you.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. i want to what are the configuration you enabled or added with hostapd.conf and android.conf. and which wifi chip are you used.? Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Needs to add the string (wps_state, eap_server) in the following files,

system/netd/server/SoftapController.cpp

```
int SoftapController::setSoftap(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int hidden  = 0;
int channel = AP_CHANNEL_DEFAULT;

int wps_state = 2;

if (argc < 5) {
  ALOGE("Softap set is missing arguments. Please use:");
  ALOGE("softap <wlan iface> <SSID> <hidden/broadcast> <channel> <wpa2?-psk|open> <passphrase>");
  return ResponseCode: : CommandSyntaxError;
}

if (!strcasecmp(argv[4], "hidden"))
  hidden = 1;

if (argc >= 5) {
  channel = atoi(argv[5]);
if (channel <= 0)
  channel = AP_CHANNEL_DEFAULT;
}

std::string wbuf(StringPrintf("interface=%s\n"
  "driver=nl80211\n"
  "ctrl_interface=/data/misc/wifi/hostapd\n"
  "ssid=%s\n"
  "channel=%d\n"
  "ieee80211n=1\n"
  "hw_mode=%c\n"
  "ignore_broadcast_ssid=%d, eap_server = 1, wps_state = %d\n",
  argv[2], argv[3], channel, (channel <= 14) ? 'g' : 'a', hidden,wps_state));

std::string fbuf;
if (argc > 7) {
char psk_str[2*SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH+1];
if (!strcmp(argv[6], "wpa-psk")) {
  if (!generatePsk(argv[3], argv[7], psk_str)) {
    return ResponseCode: : OperationFailed;
  }
  fbuf = StringPrintf("%swpa=3\nwpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP\nwpa_psk=%s\n", wbuf.c_str(), psk_str);
  } else if (!strcmp(argv[6], "wpa2-psk")) {
    if (!generatePsk(argv[3], argv[7], psk_str)) {
      return ResponseCode: : OperationFailed;
    }
    fbuf = StringPrintf("%swpa=2\nrsn_pairwise=CCMP\nwpa_psk=%s\n", wbuf.c_str(), psk_str);
  } else if (!strcmp(argv[6], "open")) {
    fbuf = wbuf;
  }
} else if (argc > 6) {
  if (!strcmp(argv[6], "open")) {
    fbuf = wbuf;
  }
} else {
  fbuf = wbuf;
}

if (!WriteStringToFile(fbuf, HOSTAPD_CONF_FILE, 0660, AID_SYSTEM, AID_WIFI)) {
ALOGE("Cannot write to \"%s\": %s", HOSTAPD_CONF_FILE, strerror(errno));
  return ResponseCode::OperationFailed;
} else {
  return ResponseCode::SoftapStatusResult;
}
```

Testing,

hostapd_cli  wps_pbc