# Is it possible to configure WPS in create_ap?

Tags: wifi, wifi-hotspot, wps

I have a PC which can emit a wifi hotspot. Currently I can use create_ap to create a WiFi hotspot in 2.4GHz without problem.

I also have a wifi extender which requires the wifi emitter to enter WPS mode in order to extend the wifi signal.

Could create_ap be switched into WPS mode?

Comment: would this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372902/how-to-configure-hostapd-conf-for-wps-push-button

Comment: @A.B That post is related to hostapd which create_ap depends on, but I don't think create_ap allows the user to configure the underlying hostapd

Comment: Then without modifying `create_ap` the answer to the question is no: the word "wps", used in hostapd's configuration, doesn't appear anywhere in [`create_ap`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oblique/create_ap/master/create_ap)

Comment: The `create_ap` will auto create a temporary `hostapd.conf` file , it doesn't include the wps parameter.